# Drinking water from glass instead of plastic

Tags: water, toxins, plastic

I recently learnt that it's healthier to store drinking water in glass objects instead of plastic ones.

Okay, this would work if I use tap water but what about if I buy water that has already stayed for who knows how long in a plastic bottle? Is there a point to transfer the water into a glass bottle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have attended a conference on water conservation in 2014, there was an interesting discussion about the purity of water and water storage. Your question reminded me of that.

To answer your question, We have to make it clear, on how long are we gonna store the water for, we all know that basic material for glass is silica and for plastic it is carbon. Silica is more stable than carbon so it doesn't oxidize soon, carbon too is stable but when compared to the silica carbon relatively oxidizes in a long run. Resulting in browning of the plastic and becoming greasy.

So, if you are storing just for days, or weeks (after opening), it is fine to use plastic. Glass is always a better option.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help! One question, though. You mentioned "after opening". Does it mean that if I do not open the vacuum sealed water bottles I can store the water there for as long as I want?

Comment: Well, It can't be said that as long as you want, but unopened will last longer than the opened.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your post however post on this site have links and sources to verify the information. If you could edit that in that would be greatly appreciated. For any more questions please consult the help center or ask here. Thank You and I hope to see you around :)